# Gmail get messages and post them to a server [google app script?]

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I need to get some spam messages from a set of gmail inboxes and post them to a server.

My initial idea was to write a chrome extension, which when installed would be activated every time the user visited its inbox, but I couldn't do it that way, since there is no access to spam messages (just unread ones through a XML file).

Then I discovered google APP script and succesfully wrote the script I needed.. but the problem is, how can I use that script for other accounts? At the moment a user needs a lot of configuration to make it work (script has to be shared, user has to install google app script, set a trigger for the function).

IS there a user friendly way to make this work? Even in other ways? I have no access to inbox passwords though.

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should design a User Interface, deploy your app as a webApp with parameter 'run as user executing the app' and add the trigger creation in the script itself.

All this should not be too hard...

Feel free to ask for assistance if you meet some issue.

In this case don't forget to post your code if you want useful tips.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your advices and I succesfully did what I planned to do!